# Connection issues with neo4j and neo4jclient

Tags: macos, sockets, neo4j, vmware

I am using Neo4jclient in an .NET application that I am building on a VM (VMWare--Windows 7) on a mac (OS X 10.9.3). The Neo4J database is running on the Mac OS. When I try to connect to the Neo4j database I get the same error in the browser as I do when I debug the code:

[Fiddler] The socket connection to 172.16.20.38 failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 172.16.20.38:7474

The same message is received using port 80. However I can ping the Mac OS from the Windows 7 VM.

I have tried changing the networking from NAT to bridged (autodetect) on the VM settings on the Mac, to no avail.

I have searched quite a bit and I know there are certain files that can be changed on Linux machines that can resolve this issue, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to edit the settings in the `conf/neo4j-server.properties`.

Look for the following

```
# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

And uncomment out the last line `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0`. This should enable you to connect from another machine.